# Get the winner from Tic Tac Toe

Tags: java, swing, jframe

so i have to hand in tomorrow a game of Tic Tac Toe. I managed to code pretty much all of it but i cant get it to get the Winner.

So far this is what i have:

```
package TicTacToe;

public class TicTacToeMain {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    TicTacToe t = new TicTacToe();
    t.setVisible(true);
}


}


package TicTacToe;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class TicTacToe extends javax.swing.JFrame {
public TicTacToe() {
    initComponents();
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    jRadioButton2 = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
    jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton3 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton4 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton5 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton6 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton7 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton8 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton9 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton10 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton11 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton12 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jRadioButton1 = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
    jRadioButton3 = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();

    jRadioButton2.setText("jRadioButton2");

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    jButton1.setEnabled(false);
    jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jButton2.setEnabled(false);
    jButton2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton2ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jButton3.setEnabled(false);
    jButton3.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton3ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jButton4.setEnabled(false);
    jButton4.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton4ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jButton5.setEnabled(false);
    jButton5.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton5ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jButton6.setEnabled(false);
    jButton6.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton6ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jButton7.setEnabled(false);
    jButton7.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton7ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jButton8.setEnabled(false);
    jButton8.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton8ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jButton9.setEnabled(false);
    jButton9.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton9ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jButton10.setText("New Game");
    jButton10.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton10ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jButton11.setText("Reset");
    jButton11.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton11ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jButton12.setText("Quit");
    jButton12.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton12ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jRadioButton1.setText("Player 1 ( X )");
    jRadioButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jRadioButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jRadioButton3.setText("Player 1 ( O )");
    jRadioButton3.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jRadioButton3ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(jRadioButton1)
            .addGap(62, 62, 62)
            .addComponent(jRadioButton3)
            .addGap(93, 93, 93))
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jButton5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 135, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(jButton6, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 135, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(jButton4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 135, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 135, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(jButton2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 135, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(jButton3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 135, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, false)
                        .addComponent(jButton10, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(jButton8, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 135, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                        .addComponent(jButton11, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(jButton9, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 135, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                        .addComponent(jButton12, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(jButton7, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 135, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))))
            .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jRadioButton1)
                .addComponent(jRadioButton3))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 123, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(jButton2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 123, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(jButton3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 123, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jButton5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 123, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(jButton6, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 123, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(jButton4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 123, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jButton8, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 123, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(jButton9, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 123, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(jButton7, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 123, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jButton10)
                .addComponent(jButton11)
                .addComponent(jButton12)))
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

int count = 2;

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:

    if (jRadioButton1.isSelected()) {
        if (count % 2 == 0) {
            count++;
            jButton1.setText("X");
            jButton1.setEnabled(false);
        } else {
            count++;
            jButton1.setText("O");
            jButton1.setEnabled(false);
        }
    } else {
        if (jRadioButton3.isSelected()) {
            if ((count % 2 == 0)) {
                count++;
                jButton1.setText("O");
                jButton1.setEnabled(false);
            } else {
                count++;
                jButton1.setText("X");
                jButton1.setEnabled(false);
            }
        }
    }
}                                        

private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:

    if (jRadioButton1.isSelected()) {
        if (count % 2 == 0) {
            count++;
            jButton2.setText("X");
            jButton2.setEnabled(false);
        } else {
            count++;
            jButton2.setText("O");
            jButton2.setEnabled(false);
        }
    } else {
        if (jRadioButton3.isSelected()) {
            if ((count % 2 == 0)) {
                count++;
                jButton2.setText("O");
                jButton2.setEnabled(false);
            } else {
                count++;
                jButton2.setText("X");
                jButton2.setEnabled(false);
            }
        }
    }
}                                        

private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:

    if (jRadioButton1.isSelected()) {
        if (count % 2 == 0) {
            count++;
            jButton3.setText("X");
            jButton3.setEnabled(false);
        } else {
            count++;
            jButton3.setText("O");
            jButton3.setEnabled(false);
        }
    } else {
        if (jRadioButton3.isSelected()) {
            if ((count % 2 == 0)) {
                count++;
                jButton3.setText("O");
                jButton3.setEnabled(false);
            } else {
                count++;
                jButton3.setText("X");
                jButton3.setEnabled(false);
            }
        }
    }
}                                        

private void jButton5ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    if (jRadioButton1.isSelected()) {
        if (count % 2 == 0) {
            count++;
            jButton5.setText("X");
            jButton5.setEnabled(false);
        } else {
            count++;
            jButton5.setText("O");
            jButton5.setEnabled(false);
        }
    } else {
        if (jRadioButton3.isSelected()) {
            if ((count % 2 == 0)) {
                count++;
                jButton5.setText("O");
                jButton5.setEnabled(false);
            } else {
                count++;
                jButton5.setText("X");
                jButton5.setEnabled(false);
            }
        }
    }
}                                        

private void jButton6ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    if (jRadioButton1.isSelected()) {
        if (count % 2 == 0) {
            count++;
            jButton6.setText("X");
            jButton6.setEnabled(false);
        } else {
            count++;
            jButton6.setText("O");
            jButton6.setEnabled(false);
        }
    } else {
        if (jRadioButton3.isSelected()) {
            if ((count % 2 == 0)) {
                count++;
                jButton6.setText("O");
                jButton6.setEnabled(false);
            } else {
                count++;
                jButton6.setText("X");
                jButton6.setEnabled(false);
            }
        }
    }
}                                        

private void jButton4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    if (jRadioButton1.isSelected()) {
        if (count % 2 == 0) {
            count++;
            jButton4.setText("X");
            jButton4.setEnabled(false);
        } else {
            count++;
            jButton4.setText("O");
            jButton4.setEnabled(false);
        }
    } else {
        if (jRadioButton3.isSelected()) {
            if ((count % 2 == 0)) {
                count++;
                jButton4.setText("O");
                jButton4.setEnabled(false);
            } else {
                count++;
                jButton4.setText("X");
                jButton4.setEnabled(false);
            }
        }
    }
}                                        

private void jButton8ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    if (jRadioButton1.isSelected()) {
        if (count % 2 == 0) {
            count++;
            jButton8.setText("X");
            jButton8.setEnabled(false);
        } else {
            count++;
            jButton8.setText("O");
            jButton8.setEnabled(false);
        }
    } else {
        if (jRadioButton3.isSelected()) {
            if ((count % 2 == 0)) {
                count++;
                jButton8.setText("O");
                jButton8.setEnabled(false);
            } else {
                count++;
                jButton8.setText("X");
                jButton8.setEnabled(false);
            }
        }
    }
}                                        

private void jButton9ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    if (jRadioButton1.isSelected()) {
        if (count % 2 == 0) {
            count++;
            jButton9.setText("X");
            jButton9.setEnabled(false);
        } else {
            count++;
            jButton9.setText("O");
            jButton9.setEnabled(false);
        }
    } else {
        if (jRadioButton3.isSelected()) {
            if ((count % 2 == 0)) {
                count++;
                jButton9.setText("O");
                jButton9.setEnabled(false);
            } else {
                count++;
                jButton9.setText("X");
                jButton9.setEnabled(false);
            }
        }
    }
}                                        

private void jButton7ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    if (jRadioButton1.isSelected()) {
        if (count % 2 == 0) {
            count++;
            jButton7.setText("X");
            jButton7.setEnabled(false);
        } else {
            count++;
            jButton7.setText("O");
            jButton7.setEnabled(false);
        }
    } else {
        if (jRadioButton3.isSelected()) {
            if ((count % 2 == 0)) {
                count++;
                jButton7.setText("O");
                jButton7.setEnabled(false);
            } else {
                count++;
                jButton7.setText("X");
                jButton7.setEnabled(false);
            }
        }
    }
}                                        

private void jButton10ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    jButton1.setText("");
    jButton1.setEnabled(false);
    jButton2.setText("");
    jButton2.setEnabled(false);
    jButton3.setText("");
    jButton3.setEnabled(false);
    jButton4.setText("");
    jButton4.setEnabled(false);
    jButton5.setText("");
    jButton5.setEnabled(false);
    jButton6.setText("");
    jButton6.setEnabled(false);
    jButton7.setText("");
    jButton7.setEnabled(false);
    jButton8.setText("");
    jButton8.setEnabled(false);
    jButton9.setText("");
    jButton9.setEnabled(false);
    jRadioButton1.setSelected(false);
    jRadioButton3.setSelected(false);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Seleccione ( X ) o ( O )");

}                                         

private void jButton12ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    System.exit(0);

}                                         

private void jRadioButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    if (jRadioButton1.isSelected()) {
        jButton1.setEnabled(true);
        jButton2.setEnabled(true);
        jButton3.setEnabled(true);
        jButton4.setEnabled(true);
        jButton5.setEnabled(true);
        jButton6.setEnabled(true);
        jButton7.setEnabled(true);
        jButton8.setEnabled(true);
        jButton9.setEnabled(true);
    }

}                                             

private void jRadioButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
    // TODO add your handling code here:

    if (jRadioButton3.isSelected()) {
        jButton1.setEnabled(true);
        jButton2.setEnabled(true);
        jButton3.setEnabled(true);
        jButton4.setEnabled(true);
        jButton5.setEnabled(true);
        jButton6.setEnabled(true);
        jButton7.setEnabled(true);
        jButton8.setEnabled(true);
        jButton9.setEnabled(true);
    }
}                                             

private void jButton11ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    jButton1.setText("");
    jButton1.setEnabled(false);
    jButton2.setText("");
    jButton2.setEnabled(false);
    jButton3.setText("");
    jButton3.setEnabled(false);
    jButton4.setText("");
    jButton4.setEnabled(false);
    jButton5.setText("");
    jButton5.setEnabled(false);
    jButton6.setText("");
    jButton6.setEnabled(false);
    jButton7.setText("");
    jButton7.setEnabled(false);
    jButton8.setText("");
    jButton8.setEnabled(false);
    jButton9.setText("");
    jButton9.setEnabled(false);
    jRadioButton1.setSelected(false);
    jRadioButton3.setSelected(false);
    count=0;
}                                         

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new TicTacToe().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton10;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton11;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton12;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton3;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton4;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton5;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton6;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton7;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton8;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton9;
private javax.swing.JRadioButton jRadioButton1;
private javax.swing.JRadioButton jRadioButton2;
private javax.swing.JRadioButton jRadioButton3;
// End of variables declaration                   

//if(jButton1.equals(jButton2) && jButton2.equals(jButton3)&& (jButton2) != "")) {

if(jButton1.getText().equals(jButton2.getText()) && (jButton2.getText.equals(jButton3.getText)) && (jButton2.getText() != "") {
  ganador = true;        
}
}
```

The game works just fine, but i am not sure how to get the winner.

1. I am not sure where exactly in the code i need to place it.
2. First i tried

   ```
   if((jButton1.getText())==(jButton2.getText())&&((jButton2.getText())==(jButton3.getText()){
   ```

   ganador = true;
   }

but it says it's missing the return statement. Then i changed the code in order to use .equals but it says its missing a return statement again .

```
     if(jButton1.getText().equals(jButton2.getText()) && (jButton2.getText.equals(jButton3.getText)) && (jButton2.getText() != "") {
  ganador = true;        
}
```

Also, i place this part of the code at the end but not sure if that's the problem.

Comment: I am not going to bother sifting through all that code in order to try and find the method or component you need help with.

Comment: Can you clarify your: I am getting errors a bit so I can expand my answer. That is a huge amount of code to shift through with such little information.

Comment: BTW, this project may have been easier to modularize if you had taken a proper object-oriented approach (which is what you ought to be doing if you are going to use an object-oriented language like Java).  Your entire program is written in one single class in a horrific tangle of spaghetti code.  You may as well have written this in BASIC.

Answer (score 2):

The `getText()` function in `AbstractButton` returns a `String`, in java you need to compare `Strings` using the `.equals(otherString)` function

Edit: in regards to your missing return statement. That also means your code there isn't complete as all those methods are `void`. But if you say a function is: `public boolean doSomething()` then you need a return statement that actually returns a `boolean` such as: `return ganador`.

Comment: I edited my code but it is still not working. Where in the code should this be placed?

Answer (score 0):

To further what Simon has said, you want to be implementing this along the lines of:
`jButton1.getText().equals( jButton2.getText() )`